# Product of Pauli-matrix exponentials

Tags: homework-and-exercises, operators, commutator, mathematics

Given Pauli matrices $\sigma_x = \begin{pmatrix}  0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\sigma_z = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$, can one write $e^{\alpha \sigma_z} e^{\beta \sigma_x}$ in terms of $e^{\beta \sigma_x} e^{\alpha \sigma_z}$ ($\alpha$, $\beta$ are some complex numbers). For example, is it possible to find some $M$ such that

\begin{equation}
e^{\alpha \sigma_z} e^{\beta \sigma_x} = e^{\beta \sigma_x} e^{\alpha \sigma_z}M?
\end{equation}

Comment: Sure: Just calculate $M= e^{-\alpha\sigma_z} e^{-\beta\sigma_x} e^{\alpha\sigma_z} e^{\beta\sigma_x}$

Comment: Each exponential has a compact expression in terms of sigma matrices. But are you ***sure*** there are no i factors in front of the Greek letter hyperbolic angles to make your exponentials unitary??

Comment: Don't use BCH. It's a useful trick to use the vector notation $\vec \sigma$. In general, for any vector $\vec u$, $(\vec u\cdot \vec \sigma)^2 = u^2$ so from the power series:$$\exp(\vec u\cdot \vec \sigma) = \cosh(u) +\sinh(u)\hat u\cdot \vec \sigma$$ with $\hat u = \vec u/u$ the normalised vector. Using also the product rule:$$(\vec u\cdot \vec \sigma)(\vec u\cdot \vec \sigma) =( \vec u\cdot \vec v)\mathbb 1 +i(\vec u\times\vec v)\cdot \vec \sigma$$ you can calculate anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [standard formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Exponential_of_a_Pauli_vector),
$$
e^{\alpha \sigma_z}= I\cosh \alpha + \sigma_z  \sinh\alpha = , \\
e^{\beta \sigma_x}= I\cosh \beta + \sigma_x  \sinh\beta ,
$$
to compute the quadruple product suggested in the comments,
$$
M=e^{-\alpha \sigma_z}e^{-\beta \sigma_x}e^{\alpha \sigma_z}e^{\beta \sigma_x}\\ = 
e^{-ia\sigma_z}e^{-ib\sigma_x}e^{ia \sigma_z} e^{ib\sigma_x}\\
= \Biggl (I\cos a\cos b+i\left (-\sigma_y\sin a \sin b  -\sigma_z \sin a \cos b-\sigma_x\sin b \cos a  \right ) \Biggr)\\ \times \Biggl ( I\cos a\cos b   +i\left (-\sigma_y \sin a \sin b  + \sigma_z \sin a \cos b   + \sigma_x  \sin b \cos a  \right ) \Biggr)\\
= I(1-2\sin^2a ~\sin^2 b)\\ +i\Bigl (\sigma_x 2\sin^2 a\sin b\cos b-\sigma_y 2\sin a \cos a\sin b\cos b -\sigma_z 2\sin^2b\sin a \cos a \Bigr ).
$$
Can you take it from here? You might be amused taking $a=\pi$, and seeing it geometrically, or else $b=\pi$ .

Note the all-important unitarity constraint/check: the sum of the squares of the coefficients of I and the σ s, respectively amounts to 1, as it should!

From the coefficient of the identity matrix, you find its  arccos, θ, and you just confirmed that the coefficient of the $i\hat n\cdot \vec \sigma$, for normalized unit $\hat n$,  messier  to write down, *must* be $\sin\theta$! So,
$$
M=e^{i\theta \hat n\cdot \vec \sigma}.
$$

For imaginary hyperbolic angles, so real trigonometric angles, this amounts to a quadruple group element product for *SU(2)*, dubbed the group (not algebra) [commutator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator).

Comment: I wanted $M=e^{S}$ for some $S$. In particular when $\alpha = i a$ and $\beta = i b$ for real $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Ok, I obtained the form of $M$ in terms of hyperbolic functions, but how can I find $S$ to put it in exponential form?

Comment: Add the angles to get a compact expression just as in Wikipedia. If you want real angles, why do you *bother* with hyperbolic angles at all?

Comment: Have you read and understood the WP section on addition of rotations? Collect your expression into the form $I \cos\theta +i\hat n\cdot \vec \sigma \sin\theta= e^{i\theta \hat n\cdot \vec \sigma }$...

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to complete it. Yes I am reading the WP too.

Comment: Your expression is wrong, for the $a=\pi$ or $b=\pi$ limit, when the coefficients of I should be 1. I think I get $\cos^2a+\sin^2a ~\cos2b$ which has the correct limits.

Comment: $M = I m_0 + \sigma_x m_x + \sigma_y m_y + \sigma_z m_z$ with $m_0 = 1 -2\sin^2a \sin^2b$, $m_x = \sin^2a \sin b \cos b$,  $m_y = \sin a \sin b \cos a \cos b$, and $m_z = 0$.

Comment: Fails the unitarity constraint. See my edit.

Comment: Absolutely clear! Thanks!!